# Loading a 16KB file in Android takes 35 seconds?

Tags: java, android, memory

I have a memory problem with Android on my Nexus One tablet that I was hoping for some insight.

I am making a board game which is represented by array of 64 ints. When the Activity's onPause() is called it saves the current board, as well as each board from previous turns (up to 64 turns). This takes about 600ms, no problem. When onResume() is called, and it is time to load the information, it can take up to 35 seconds with a full undo history!

```
        FileInputStream fis = c.openFileInput(filename);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(fis);
        int nprev = sc.nextInt(); // Number of previous boards to load
        sc.nextLine();
        for(int k = 0; k < nprev; k++) {
            int[] parr = new int[bsize*bsize];
            for(int i = 0; i < bsize; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < bsize; j++) {
                    int v = sc.nextInt();
                    parr[i*bsize+j]=v;
                }
                sc.nextLine();
            }
            prevBoards.push(parr);
        }

        sc.close();
        fis.close();
    }
```

bsize=8. So it simply creates int[64] arrays, loads numbers in to them, and pushes them on to a stack (prevBoards). At most it could push 64, int[64] arrays on the stack. Still, am I wrong in thinking that this takes way too long?

I noticed that while it is loading, LogCat is spammed with messages like "GC_CONCURRENT freed 402K, 7% free 7500K/8052K ..." Which doesn't make sense because the arrays should only take up 4*64*64/1024=16KB of memory at most?

Comment: Try encapsulating FileInputStream with a BufferedInputStream

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, per se, but have you considered using Java's native object serialization?  This is the kind of thing it is for.

Comment: Is it possible something else is taking up all that time? Have you printed the time just before/after this bit of code and/or set breakpoints?

Comment: Object Serialization does away with having to read each line from the file.You can directly save the Object structure into a file,and reload it back with minimal and fast IO.instead of saving 64 individual board positions into a file and loading them back,you can instead create a 2 day array 64*64 and save the array(serialise the array) directly into a file and load the array back from the file..

Comment: Could you post these LogCat messages please? How many do you get? About the only thing I can think of looking at the code is have you done `prevBoards.clear()` to flush the stack? Does `prevBoards.ensureCapacity(nprev);` before the loop help?

Comment: Encapsulating with a BufferedInputStream did not have any noticeable effect on the problem.

Comment: It must have somehow been a memory leak or something. There were 20+ of those (garbage collector?) messages each saying "paused 15 ms", that was what slowed it down so much.

It took about 5 minutes to simply make the whole "game" object Serializable. Saving and loading are both incredibly faster, code is a lot cleaner, and it ended up saving me a bunch of time. I'm still curious what went wrong doing it the brute force way, but this solution ended up being the best on all accounts. Thankyou.

Comment: I think the problem is perhaps not with the deserialisation itself. If Java thinks that it can't clear enough memory for something using  mark & sweep, it will "stop the world" i.e. pause everything and do a manual sweep to clear as much memory as possible. This cannot use multiple threads and is painfully slow. If you have a memory leak, that would trigger such a situation.

Comment: Have you tried using the TraceView to figure out what is causing the delay?

Comment: This should be closed now.  The OP has solved his problem.

Answer (score 2):

I just reproduced your problem saving 65 integer, and loading them again in onResume using your code. It took the activity 3s to load these 65 integers!

I did some profiling to find where the code is loosing the time and found that the **Scanner** class is your main problem. It seems it uses some regular expressions, nearly all the cpu time was used in the compiliation of a pattern which was called 65 times.

You should avoid the usage of the scanner class and find a better way to store your integer values. Maybe take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html